# An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing'

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, syntax-error, user-defined-functions

```py
import ast
import json
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([StructField('in_network', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('billing_code', StringType(), True), StructField('billing_code_type', StringType(), True), StructField('billing_code_type_version', StringType(), True), StructField('description', StringType(), True), StructField('name', StringType(), True), StructField('negotiated_rates', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('negotiated_prices', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('additional_information', StringType(), True), StructField('billing_class', StringType(), True), StructField('billing_code_modifier', ArrayType(StringType(), True), True), StructField('expiration_date', StringType(), True), StructField('negotiated_rate', DoubleType(), True), StructField('negotiated_type', StringType(), True), StructField('service_code', ArrayType(StringType(), True), True)]), True), True), StructField('provider_references', ArrayType(LongType(), True), True)]), True), True), StructField('negotiation_arrangement', StringType(), True)]), True), True), StructField('last_updated_on', StringType(), True), StructField('provider_references', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('provider_group_id', LongType(), True), StructField('provider_groups', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('npi', ArrayType(LongType(), True), True), StructField('tin', StructType([StructField('type', StringType(), True), StructField('value', StringType(), True)]), True)]), True), True)]), True), True), StructField('reporting_entity_name', StringType(), True), StructField('reporting_entity_type', StringType(), True), StructField('version', StringType(), True)])

dict_to_json = F.udf(lambda x: json.dumps(ast.literal_eval(x)))
df = spark.read.text("dbfs:/mnt/transparency/mkjl/in_frt_qSW.json").withColumn("value", F.from_json(dict_to_json("value"), schema)).select("value.*")
df.show()
```

Error:

```
PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing', from , line 6. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 6, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 62, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "", line 0
    
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I'm getting this error when I try to show or write the dataframe.

Comment: @ZygD - Multiline is not working for huge json file

Answer (score 0):

You could try [JSON reader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json.html) instead of text reader. Since you already have the schema, it may work:

```py
df = spark.read.json("dbfs:/mnt/transparency/mkjl/in_frt_qSW.json", schema, multiLine=True)
```

This way you would also avoid the inefficient `udf`.